# Azure REST API for fetching contact details of all users from azure portal

Tags: java, azure, azure-functions

I am developing a java application which will need the contact details from azure AD.
I am not getting any REST API to fetch the details.
After lot of searching I got the below GET user entity request url which I am using, but it is only giving me the below output.
Can someone help me with how can I get the contact details of the users(currently I created only 1 user in azure portal)

**GET URL:**

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{{subscriptionID}}/resourceGroups/{{ResourceGroup}}/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/{{ServiceName}}/users?api-version=2019-01-01
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
"type": "Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/users",
"name": "1",
"properties": {
    "firstName": "Administrator",
    "lastName": "",
    "email": "XXXXX@outlook.com",
    "state": "active",
    "registrationDate": "2019-07-09T19:02:48.06Z",
    "note": null,
    "identities": [{
                "provider": "Azure",
                "id": "XXXXXX@outlook.com"
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use graph API's.Below endpoint will return all users in organization

> https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users

[image]